# preg_match to remove stray HTML

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm having trouble eliminating some stray portions of HTML that are ending up in an automatically generated excerpt for a WordPress site. For example, at the beginning of an excerpt I'll see:

> href=”https://stackoverflow.com”>Excerpt text starts here...

or at the end of an excerpt:

> ...excerpt text ends here <a

So it seems what I'm looking for is a method to match and remove any string of non-space characters at the start of the excerpt that end with ">" or any string of non-space characters at the end of the excerpt that start with "<".

Answer (score 1):

If the excerpt doesn't contain `<` and `>` characters, there are a couple of approaches you can take. One to remove the segments as you describe in your question using `preg_replace`, the other to use `preg_match` to find a set of characters between a `>` and a `<`. For example:

```
$excerpts = array('href=”https://stackoverflow.com”>Excerpt text starts here... ...excerpt text ends here <a',
    'href=”https://stackoverflow.com”>Excerpt text starts here... ...excerpt text ends here',
    'Excerpt text starts here... ...excerpt text ends here <a',
    'Excerpt text starts here... ...excerpt text ends here'
);

foreach ($excerpts as $excerpt) {
    preg_match('/(?<=^|>)[^<>]+(?=<|$)/', $excerpt, $matches);
    echo $matches[0] . PHP_EOL;
}

foreach ($excerpts as $excerpt) {
    echo preg_replace(array('/.*>/', '/<.*$/'), '', $excerpt) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Excerpt text starts here... ...excerpt text ends here
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/7ZkmG)